# Firefox sdk - access popup opened

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I'm currently working on a Firefox addon, and I was wondering if is there any way to access pop-up, in other words a window that was open using Javascript function .open().

If I access all tabs the popups are not there, if I access all windows the popups windows are not there.

```
 //
 var allWindows = window_utils.windows(null);
 //
 var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
 for (let tab of tabs)
     console.log(tab.title);
```

Comment: do you need access to *any* popup or just to one popup that you know? if the case is the later and you know the url, you can use [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod)

Comment: that could be useful too, thanks! because if I want all, I assume I could do include: '*' , please answer the question so that I can accept your answer thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the popup's url you can use a [PageMod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) to detect when it loads, its url, etc.